# translating time_ago_in_words to french for I18n in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I translate `time_ago_in_words`?

I am having a missing translation text for the fr locale:

> Translation missing: fr.datetime.distance_in_words.x_days   ago|

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to create the corresponding structure in under the `datetime` key in your fr.yml locale in `config/locales/`:

```
  datetime:
    distance_in_words:
      about_x_hours:
        one: environ une heure
        other: environ %{count} heures
      about_x_months:
        one: environ un mois
        other: environ %{count} mois
      about_x_years:
        one: environ un an
        other: environ %{count} ans
      almost_x_years:
        one: presqu'un an
        other: presque %{count} ans
      half_a_minute: une demi-minute
      less_than_x_minutes:
        zero: moins d'une minute
        one: moins d'une minute
        other: moins de %{count} minutes
      less_than_x_seconds:
        zero: moins d'une seconde
        one: moins d'une seconde
        other: moins de %{count} secondes
      over_x_years:
        one: plus d'un an
        other: plus de %{count} ans
      x_days:
        one: 1 jour
        other: "%{count} jours"
      x_minutes:
        one: 1 minute
        other: "%{count} minutes"
      x_months:
        one: 1 mois
        other: "%{count} mois"
      x_years:
        one: un an
        other: "%{count} ans"
      x_seconds:
        one: 1 seconde
        other: "%{count} secondes"
```

You can see the full example [here](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/fr.yml).