# How to split distance_in_words for minutes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-6

For hours, months and years there are the [following](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/locale/en.yml) translations:

```yaml
about_x_hours:
  one:   "about 1 hour"
  other: "about %{count} hours"
about_x_months:
  one:   "about 1 month"
  other: "about %{count} months"
about_x_years:
  one:   "about 1 year"
  other: "about %{count} years"

x_months:
  one:   "1 month"
  other: "%{count} months"
x_months:
  one: in 1 month
  other: "in %{count} months"
x_years:
  one: in 1 year
  other: "in %{count} years"
```

But for `x_minutes` and `x_days` there is no `about_x_minutes` and `about_x_days`.

Please tell me how can I add these options for translations?

Comment: I found this too, which should work : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46062087/12108872

Comment: @NicolasIniesta I have `less_than_x_minutes`, but it doesn't work the way I want it to (like the `about_*` examples)